# How can I apply BeautifulSoup on a part of a HTML tag collected in a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a CSV where one column has strings with a full HTML table on each row.

I want to navigate those tables and extract the TDs corresponding to some definite THs. BeautifulSoup, obviously, raises an error saying it can't read strings, only HTML.

What should I do? Is Beautiful Soup really the best way?

Comment: Can you please share, what you had tried so far, your data or some example data..?

Comment: Maybe you want to show some code and data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a HTML string and parse the data, a better option might be the etree module from lxml,

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(your_html_string)
```

You can parse the `tree` object by passing in the xpath to the desired elements.

```
tds = tree.xpath('the/xpath/to/yout/tds')
```

If you want the text within the tds,

```
tds = tree.xpath('the/xpath/to/yout/tds/text()')
```

Here is the link to the documentation,
https://lxml.de/parsing.html